# Jolt Transforme Json

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have this JSON

```json
[
  {
    "nomclient": "diattara",
    "prix": 15,
    "ville": "Paris",
    "typeproduit": "boisson",
    "produit": [
      "COCA",
      "RedBull"
    ]
  },
  {
    "nomclient": "kamel",
    "prix": 250,
    "ville": "Marseille",
    "typeproduit": "beurre",
    "produit": [
      "auchan"
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to apply a jolt Transforme in NIFI to get a JSON like this:

```json
[
  {
    "nomclient": "diattara",
    "prix": 15,
    "ville": "Paris"
  },
  {
    "nomclient": "kamel",
    "prix": 15,
    "ville": "Paris"
  }
]
```

I tried this spec but the result was not good

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ville": "ville",
        "prix": "prix"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

could you help me please

Comment: Are you saying you want the prix and ville fields to be set for all JSON objects to those in the first JSON object?

Comment: Yes exactly, I just want to see " nom client","ville", and "prix, like a kind of filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the values of the first entry's `prix` and `ville` values for all the `nomclient` entries, you can use the following spec in JoltTransformJSON:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@(1,[0].prix)": "[&1].prix",
        "@(1,[0].ville)": "[&1].ville",
        "nomclient": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

If you want to just keep the 3 fields from each entry you can use the following spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "prix": "[&1].&",
        "ville": "[&1].&",
        "nomclient": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I was looking for the second solution, thank you very much it's working